# writing array values to the same line while extracting data from json using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "hostid": "15226",
      "host": "host1",
      "groups": [
        {
          "groupid": "56",
          "name": "Group 1",
          "internal": "0",
          "flags": "0"
        },
        {
          "groupid": "112",
          "name": "Group 2",
          "internal": "0",
          "flags": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "id": 1
}
```

I am trying to extract values from it to create this line using jq:

```
15226, host1, Group 1, Group 2
```

I am able to do the following but it's not quite what I want:

```
jq -r '.result[] | .hostid + ", " + .host + ", " + .groups[].name' hostlist.json
15226, host1, Group 1
15226, host1, Group 2
```

Couldn't figure it out, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
jq -r '.result[]|[.hostid,.host,.groups[].name]|@csv'
```

Output:

```
"15226","host1","Group 1","Group 2"
```

---

`@csv` makes proper csv out of it. If you don't like that, a simple `join(',')` should be enough:

```
jq -r '.result[]|[.hostid,.host,.groups[].name]|join(",")'
```

Output:

```
15226,host1,Group 1,Group 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using reduce seems to do the trick: `.result[] | .hostid + ", " + .host + ", " + (reduce .groups[].name as $gn (""; . + $gn + " "))`

You might want to trim the output as well, as this produces and extra whitespace character.

Comment: thanks, but this produces this output (no comma between Group 1 and Group 2): 15226, host1, Group 1 Group 2

Answer (score 0):

**join** / **@csv** as described by [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) is definitely the easiest way to do this.

For reference, here is a version that uses string interpolation to build the initial part of the line and **reduce** to add the group names to it:

```
  .result[]
| reduce .groups[].name as $g (
      "\(.hostid), \(.host)"
    ; . + ", " + $g 
  )
```